# TABLA DE MULTIPLICAR EN PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x

He escrito un programa que te devuelve la tabla de multiplicar del número que le introduzcas. El programa no para hasta que el usuario le introduce un 0. Es decir, en cuanto el programa te devuelva la lista de resultados de la tabla de multiplicar te pide otro numero de nuevo.

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Al introducir otro número, el programa te devuelve una lista de resultados con el nuevo número y con el anterior.

El código es el siguiente:

```
lista = []

i = 0

salir = False

while not salir:

    numero = int(input("Introduzca un numero: "))
    if numero != 0:        
        for i in range (0,11):
            resultado = i * numero
            i = i + 1
            lista.append(resultado)
        print(lista)
    else:
        print("Adios")
        salir = True
```

Gracias de antemano por su respuesta

Comment: Te pasa porque no inicializas la variable `lista` cada vez que vuelves a pedir al usuario que introduzca otro número.

Answer (score 1):

Deberias inicializar la variable lista dentro del `while`:

```
salir = False

while not salir:
    i = 0
    lista = []
    numero = int(input("Introduzca un numero: "))
    if numero != 0:        
        for i in range (0,11):
            resultado = i * numero
            i = i + 1
            lista.append(resultado)
        print(lista)
    else:
        print("Adios")
        salir = True
```

También deberías inicializar `i` a 0 dentro del while

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me ha resultado útil

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente **recuerda borrar (clear) la lista antes de comenzar a añadir los números**.

Por otro lado, el for no requiere la declaración (e inicialización por ende) de **la variable i. Es redundante.**

Una solución podría ser esta:

```
lista = []

salir = False

while not salir:
    numero = int(input("Introduzca un numero: "))
    if numero != 0:
        lista.clear()
        for i in range (0,11):
            resultado = i * numero
            lista.append(resultado)
        print(lista)
    else:
        print("Adios")
        salir = True
```

Espero que resuelva tus dudas.